# Difference between boost.test headers

Tags: c++, boost, boost-test

What is the difference between the headers `boost/test/unit_test.hpp` and `boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp`? Both appear to work in my project and I am unsure which I should be using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp):

> included (vs. linked) version of Unit Test Framework

So you can use this if you prefer to avoid standalone library compilation. However, this solution may not be the best choice in a long run, since it requires the Unit Test Framework sources recompilation for every test module you use it with and for every change of a test module you are working on. As a result your testing cycle time may increase.

See also: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/compilation/direct-include.html